# Convert user given date (January or 01. February 2017) to a timestamp

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, timestamp, azure-language-understanding

i'm trying to parse a user input of a date to a MySQL Timestamp format (YYYY-MM-DD).
User input could be something like:

```
input -  wanted conversion
1) January - ThisYear-01-01, ThisYear-01-31
2) February 2017 - 2017-02-01, 2017-02-28
3) 01. April 2016 - 2016-04-01
4) 5.4.15 - 2015-04-05
```

P.S.: 
The examples above are the suggested formats that we want to support (supporting only some of them would be also fine).
The users are not random or international, they will always write and understand dates in this format (Day Month Year).

Handling the missing year entry or the zero (like 5/4 in #4) isn't a problem but finding a proper way to handle the mentioned possible date input formats (DD MM YY, DD MM, DD Month, Month, Month YY, DD Month YY....etc.) with something that doesn't look very ugly and long in code is a little bit hard for me to imagine.

P.S.:

D,DD,MM,YY,YYYY are short for the numerical input.

Month is for the word input variant.

Could you please tell me if there is anything that could help me to make this process easier/more readable or at least point me to the right direction?

Thanks

---

Update #1:
By looking again to my question above i see that it's missing some background information, but i didn't want to write a long description to it, just only to the wanted function. Sorry.

So here are some general infos about the Program:
The Program is a Chatbot written in C# (UWP) which accepts a user request in natural language and give back the requested info (if recognized) from a mySQL DB (DB is based on a OSTicket support system).

Internally we send the user input to [LUIS.ai](http://LUIS.ai) to get it recognized and we get back the intents and entities from the service, which we then parse to a SQL Query and send it to the DB.
The results from the DB are then sent back to the user.

Many parsed queries work perfectly, that's why i want now to extend it by letting the user give a certain date in the request (e.g. give me all the support tickets from April).
What i only want is to take this new input "April" and convert it to a MySQL TimeStamp format, so that it would be also recognized from MySQL.

My current approach is to build a string like this:

```
string convertedTS = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

And using 3 functions try to detect all three variables. But that's it for now.

E.g. "give me all the tickets from April": 
April (recognized from LUIS AI as given date) will be converted to (04)
Year will be taken from

```
DateTime.Today.Year
```

and inserted too (2018-04)
The first day is always 01 and the last day of the month will be:

```
DateTime.Today.Year
```

Final Query from the example:

```
select ..........between '2018-04-01' AND '2017-04-30'
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert to the MySQL timestamp format? Where is the user input coming from (WinForms? WebForms? MVC? WPF? Something else)?

Comment: i just edited my post it. Please read it again. sorry for the missing description.
Your questions in short:
Why: so that i can send change "01 april 2017" to "2017-04-01" to use it in the query.
Where: from LUIS.ai, originaly from user input in the UI (UWP)

Comment: Example from luis (in short):
"query": "show me all tickets from april 2017"
"entities": [
    {
      "entity": "april 2017",
      "type": "ost_ticket::created",
      "startIndex": 25,
      "endIndex": 34,
      "score": 0.958800852
    }
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that for the purpose of using it in my program.
Now i can detect and understand such inputs:
"09 11 2008"
"2017"
"today"
"yesterday"
"09/11/2002"
"march 2017"
"01.01.2010"
"01-01-2010"
"01 may 2019"
"31.October 2020"
"01 april"
"december"

If anyone is also interested in writing a similar function leave a comment, because the code is almost 300 lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about formatting the years, months, days, etc, you're doing it wrong. You have C#, and you have a date string from the user. Your concern is getting that string into a C# **DateTime** value. MySql has no part of this.

Once you have the DateTime value, let your connection provider worry about formatting via parameterized queries:

```
DateTime d = GetMyDateTimeValueFromUser();
string sql = "pretend SQL comnand with a datetime @variable";
using (var cn = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@variable", MySqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = d;
    cn.Open();

    //pick one.
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

No special SQL format needed. **If you're not using parameterized queries, *you're not doing it right!*** This applies to much more than just DateTime values. **All** data used in an SQL statement should be handled this way. This has security and performance implications that go way beyond simple date values. Go parameters, or go home (I mean that: go home. Don't write bad code. We don't need any more.)

As it applies to the question, it means the problem is *entirely* about parsing a string to a C# DateTime value. The next step of moving this data to SQL is just not relevant. Thankfully, .Net has some options for you here. Specifically, take a look at the Parse family of functions, including:

```
DateTime.Parse()
DateTime.TryParse()
DateTime.ParseExact()
DateTime.TryParseExact()
```

The latter two allow you specify a *set* of allowed formats that can match the formats actually seen by your system. NuGet can be a further resource in this area.

What's that, you say? You want to allow the user to input *anything*? That just won't work. Period. Real humans can *and will* come up with far more ways to enter a date than you could possibly ever handle. Not to mention you need to know what to do when a British citizen inputs the value 1/2/2018 into your system, because that person almost certainly believes it means February 1, 2018, and **not** January 2. Cultural differences like this mean it is impossible to accept date inputs without some kind of contextual input filter on the front end. You **must** look to your user interface to help your users create values your code will understand... but we don't have enough info in the question to provide any guidance yet in that area.

Comment: i just edited my post. Please read it again. sorry for the missing description.